# Is it possible to install the dependencies you have in composer.json file without you have composer as tool in you machine?

Tags: composer-php, phpstorm, php-7.1

[image]

I'm trying to put this app working but unfortunately whenever I try to install all dependencies inside `composer.json` file as you can see in the image above I'm getting that error. I don't know what's going on, I don't have composer installed as tool itself for dependency management in PHP. Is it that are causing this error?

*PHP 7.1 is the version of PHP that I'm using.

Comment: You definitely have Composer installed somewhere because this error is thrown by Composer. Please share a screenshot of *Settings | PHP | Composer* too.

Comment: What is "that error"? Can you share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem?